# c# call access with property["propertyname"] (equal to JavaScript)

Tags: c#

How can I access a class property in C# with the propertyname. Like I could do it in JavaScript with `property["propertyname"]`?

Answer (score 2):

To access the value of a property by name, you have to use reflection:

```
var propInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
var value = propInfo.GetValue(obj);
```

Answer (score 1):

If the class in question is yours, you could override the index operator:

```
public object this[string key]
{
    get
    {
        var property = typeof(YourClass).GetProperty(key);
        return property.GetValue(this);
    }
}
```

This will enable you to access `object.Title` with `object["Title"]`.

Of course this is a stripped-down version. You probably want to handle errors and so on. Also you could cache `PropertyInfo` objects returned by `GetProperty()` into a `Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>` because using reflection is pretty slow.